# Incrementing a variable inside a function on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

My goal is being able to graph the following:

`x(n)= delta(n)+delta(n-1)+delta(n-2)+….+delta(n-10)+delta(n-11)`

I have written this code:

```
n = -15:15
e(m) = dirc(n(m));
k = 1
for m = 1 : length(n)
    while k < 12
        e_1(m) = dirc(n(m)-k);
        k = k + 1
    end
    e(m) = e(m) + e_1(m)
end

subplot(4,4,5);
stem(n,e,'m','markersize',3,'linewidth',1)
xlabel('n')
ylabel('\delta[n]') 
title ('(e)')
```

and I wrote the function dirc as follows:

```
function output = dirc(input)
output = 0;
if input == 0
    output = 1;
end
end
```

The error is

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions

As you can see, this is a terminating function, I'd like to be able to graph something like this eventually:

`x(n)= delta(n)+delta(n-1)+delta(n-2)+….`

Comment: Well, where did you exceed the dimensions of a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing us what `m` is in the second line, that's a probable source of your problems. Also, you'll have to pre-allocate the vector `e` if you want to increment its values in a loop, this can also give you out-of-bounds errors.

As for the rest of your code, you can replace `dirc(input)` with simply `input==0`, the resulting logical values will be compatible with numerical `0` and `1` (in case the `input` is scalar, which seems to be the case for you).

As a matter of fact, what you're trying to achieve is the function

```
kmax = 11;
xfun = @(n) ismember(n,0:kmax);  %// anonymous function
x(n) = xfun(n);                  %// evaluate at any specific value n
```

or if you want to compute `x(n)` for multiple values of `n` at once:

```
kmax = 11;
xfun = @(n) sum(bsxfun(@eq,n(:),0:kmax),2);%// anonymous function
xvec = xfun(-15:15);                       %// evaluate at every n simultaneously
```